# How to get a GitHub repository using Octokit C#

Tags: c#, .net, github, octokit

I'm trying to integrate GitHubAPI in a web app that I am developing. I heard that the best way to do this in C# is using Octokit library but I can't find a very explicit documentation. Now, first of all I am trying to get a repo from GitHub. When I started, I manually accessed the endpoints as shown in the GitHub API. However, it seems that doing a commit that way is not possible so I switched to Octokit but I have some problems here.

Here is my OctokitGitService class:

```
*imports here*


namespace Web.Git.Api.Services;

public class OctokitGithubClient
{
  private readonly Config _config;
  private readonly GitHubClient _gitClient;
  public List<Repository> Repositories { get; set; }

  public OctokitGithubClient(IOptions<Config> options)
  {
    _config = options.Value;

    var ghe = new Uri(_config.apiUrl);
    _gitClient= new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("web-app-v1"), ghe);

    var tokenAuth = new Credentials(_config.PAT.git);
    _gitClient.Credentials = tokenAuth;

  }

  public async Task<List<Repository>> getGithubRepository()
  { 
    var data = _gitClient.Repository.GetAllForCurrent();
    Repositories = new List<Repository>(data);   
    return Repositories;
  }
}
```

And I get this error message:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Octokit.Repository>' to 'Octokit.Repository' [/root/projects/WebAppProject/src/Web.Git.Api/Web.Git.Api.csproj]

Can someone please give me a hint? I was looking through [Octokit doc](https://octokitnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I can't find API documentations. Ty!

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about asynchronous programming in C#. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async) is a good place to start.

`GetAllForCurrent()` signature is `Task<IReadOnlyList<Repository>> GetAllForCurrent();` If we want to use this **asynchronously**, we use `await` and then we convert `IReadOnlyList<Repository>` to `List<Repository>` using `ToList()`

```
public async Task<List<Repository>> GetGithubRepositoryAsync()
{
    var repos = await _gitClient.Repository.GetAllForCurrent();
    return repos.ToList();
}
```

If we want to use it **synchronously**, one way is to use `Result` of the `Task<>`

```
public List<Repository> GetGithubRepository()
{
    return _gitClient.Repository.GetAllForCurrent().Result.ToList();
}
```

As mentioned in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types) using `Result` property is not recommended

> The Result property is a blocking property. If you try to access it before its task is finished, the thread that's currently active is blocked until the task completes and the value is available. In most cases, you should access the value by using await instead of accessing the property directly.